# ELASTICSEARCH 2.4.1. Running on Windows 2012

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, plugins

I am trying to install a plugin for ELASTICSEARCH and keep getting the following error:

> ERROR: Installation Aborted, message: Could not find gem
>   'elasticsearch-sql-master.zip (>= 0) java' in any of the gem sources
>   listed in your Gemfile or installed on this machine.

Does anyone know how I can fix this to get this plugin installed

Comment: Solved it - if anyone else has this problem just do the following

Answer (score 0):

Solved it - if anyone else has this problem just do the following - 
1  Open a command prompt. 
2. Navigate to your elasticsearch bin folder 
3. Run the following command:
plugin.bat install https://github.com/NLPchina/elasticsearch-sql/releases/download/2.4.1.0/elasticsearch-sql-2.4.1.0.zip

Should install just fine